# LINQ to XML: how to get collection of all attributes from all elements

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have some XML like this:

```
<Section xmlns=\"http:schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"> <Paragraph FontSize=\"12\" FontFamily=\"Arial\" Foreground=\"#FF000000\" FontWeight=\"Normal\" FontStyle=\"Normal\" FontStretch=\"Normal\" TextAlignment=\"Left\"> <Run FontWeight=\"Normal\" Text=\"space \" /> </Paragraph> </Section>
```

Is there a way to get a collection of all the FontWeight attributes, all the FontSize attributes, etc., regardless of the parent element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have `XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml")` you can get all attributes with `doc.Descendants().Attributes()` or all attributes of a certain name with e.g. `doc.Descendants().Attributes("FontSize")`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a file, but a string from a rich text box.

Comment: Got it -- Use Document.Parse().  This is what I was looking for, thank.