# How do I parse a SQL query to determine its tabular depencencies?

Tags: sql, parsing, directed-acyclic-graphs

Assume I have a query, eg:

```
SELECT * FROM POTATO LEFT JOIN TUBER ON POTATO.delicious = TUBER.delicious
```

Is there a library or tool that will take that query and return ["POTATO,"TUBER"], such that I can sequence a series of queries logically?

Comment: Regex? `"([A-Za-z]+)\."`

Comment: Can't assume that there'll be a dot. You can also do `SELECT * FROM POTATO b LEFT JOIN TUBER a ON a.delicious = b.delicious`

Comment: Needs to be a domain specific sol'n

Comment: Similar topic [sql-parser-library-for-java-retrieve-the-list-of-table-names-present-in-a-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572793/sql-parser-library-for-java-retrieve-the-list-of-table-names-present-in-a-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do is [execute the SQL with `SET STATISTICS XML ON`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879543/are-there-any-way-to-programmatically-execute-a-query-with-include-actual-execut). When you do that, you'll get two resultsets: the resultset of the query and a resultset containing the query plan as XML, contained as the first column in the last row.

Once you have the query plan as XML, follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551916/linq-to-xml-how-to-get-collection-of-all-attributes-from-all-elements) to get a list of all the attributes, then filter for "Table" and inspect the results.